# How do I add an autocomplete="street-address" attribute to rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapbox

I'm trying to add Mapbox autofill to my address bar on rails, for mapbox autofill to work I need to have `autocomplete="street-address` in an `input` field.

I'm using simple_form_form and I can't figure out how to add autocomplete attribute. Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @lock do |f| %>
      <div class="form_wrapper">
        <div class="form_div">
          <%= f.input :name  %>
          <%= f.input :description %>
          <mapbox-address-autofill>
          <%= f.input :address, :autocomplete => "street-address" %>
          </mapbox-address-autofill>
          <%= f.input :photo, as: :file,  label: "Link to picture" %>
          <%= f.input :special_content  %>
          <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

any ideas on how to make the autocomplete attribute work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `input_html` and pass the additional options like `class` etc.

```
<%= f.input :address, input_html: { :autocomplete => "street-address"} %>
```